# Revolve around x-axis

Tags: integration

I have this equation, $f(x)=x(2\sin(x)+x\cos(x))$ that I need to revolve around the $x$-axis from $x=0$ to $x=2$.
I found this integral of $f(x)$ to be $x^2\sin(x)+C$.

I am looking at using the disk-method which would give me the following:

$$\int_0^2\pi[x(2\sin(x)+x\cos(x))]^2\,dx$$

I know the answer ends up to be $28.613$ but I cannot figure out this integral when you square it.

Comment: Limit of integration is from 0 to 2. The $\pi$ is outside the integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a lot of hard work as I see it. Write out
$$\begin{align}(x(2\sin x+x\cos x))^2&=4x^2\sin^2x+4x^3\sin x\cos x+x^4\cos^2x\\
&=2x^2(1-\cos2x)+2x^2\sin2x+\frac12x^4(1+\cos2x)\\
&=2x^2+\frac12x^4+\left(\frac12x^4-2x^2\right)\cos2x+2x^3\sin2x\end{align}$$
Then a bunch of [tabular integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Tabular_integration_by_parts)
$$\begin{array}{lcr}\frac12x^4-2x^2&+&\frac12\sin2x\\
2x^3-4x&-&-\frac14\cos2x\\
6x^2-4&+&-\frac18\sin2x\\
12x&-&\frac1{16}\cos2x\\
12&+&\frac1{32}\sin2x\end{array}$$
And still more...
$$\begin{array}{lcr}2x^3&+&-\frac12\cos2x\\
6x^2&-&-\frac14\sin2x\\
12x&+&\frac18\cos2x\\
12&-&\frac1{16}\sin2x\end{array}$$
Adding all that up and integrating the polynomial, we get
$$\begin{align}\int_0^2\pi\left(x(2\sin x+x\cos x)\right)^2dx=\\
&=\pi\left[\frac23x^3+\frac1{10}x^5+\left(-\frac12x^3-\frac14x\right)\cos2x+\left(\frac14x^4-\frac14x^2+\frac18\right)\sin2x\right]_0^2\\
&=\pi\left[\frac{128}{15}-\frac92\cos(4)+\frac{25}8\sin(4)\right]\approx28.6190351754340406\end{align}$$
Note that that value of 28.613 was incorrect and a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram Alpha gives the indefinite integral as $$\frac{\pi}{120}(12x^5+30x^4\sin(2x)+80x^3-60x^3\cos(2x)-30x^2\sin(2x)+15\sin(2x)-30x\cos(2x))+C$$

and if so desired, this could be computed using repeated applications of integration by parts.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}\left(2x \sin(x)+x^2 \cos(x)\right)^2&=4x^2 \sin^2(x)+4x^3 \sin(x)\cos(x)+x^4\cos^2(x)\\
&= 4x^2 \left( \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2} \right)+2x^3 \sin(2x)+x^4 \left( \frac{\cos(2x)+1}{2} \right)\\
&=2x^2-2x^2\cos(2x)+2x^3\sin(2x)+x^4\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}+\frac{x^4}{2}\\
\end{align*}

All the terms are either polynomials or product of polynomials with trigonometry functions which is manageable by integration by parts.